# Codeigniter Equivalent

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am looking for a slight help, much appreciated, I have a raw spaghetti php code I am converting to codeigniter, seems to work but output not exact, What is my syntax missing

raw php

```
  function displayMenu($parent =0) {

        $query =mysql_query("SELECT * "
                . " FROM tbl_org_structure "
                . "WHERE parent_id='$parent'"

                ) or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0 ){
            echo  '<ul>';
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                echo '<li>'.$row['name'];
                displayMenu($row['id']);
                   echo '</li>'; 
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    }
```

my codeigniter equivalent

```
    function getHierarchy($parent=0){

        $hierarchy = $this->db
                ->where('parent_id',$parent)
                ->get('tbl_org_structure')
                ->result();
        $stringBuilder='<ul>';
        foreach ($hierarchy as $chainOfCommand):          
            $stringBuilder.='<li>'.$chainOfCommand->name;
            $this->getHierarchy($chainOfCommand->id);
            $stringBuilder.='</li>';
        endforeach;
        $stringBuilder.='</ul>';

 echo $stringBuilder;

    }
```

raw php output

Board of Directors

```
Chief Executive Officer (CEO)
    Finance Department
        FC
            test
        CA
    Human Resources Department (HR)
        HOR
        MO
    IT Department
        TSM
        Sys Dev
    Sales Department
        Acc M
        MD
    Production
        PC
        DM
```

codeigniter output

```
  test

FC
CA

HOR
MO

TSM
Sys Dev

Acc M
MD

PC
DM

Finance Department
Human Resources Department (HR)
IT Department
Sales Department
Production

Chief Executive Officer (CEO)

Board of Directors
```

suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're `echo`ing the results before coming back up the recursion stack, so you're travelling all the way down to a leaf in your heirarchy, echoing that leaf, coming back and echoing the parent, and so on. You should `return $stringBuilder` instead. Then you'd need the calling code to `echo getHierarchy()`.

Or, just echo everything immediately like is being done in `displayMenu`, instead of building a string.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your comment made a big difference. I understood. Cheers